# KeyError when running Main

Tags: python, python-3.x

been facing an issue when coding the last part of task 1, I always end up getting a `KeyError: "DEF"`. I am unsure if I missed a step or if I did something incorrectly. Thanks for the help

I attached the code and the snip of the problem encountered if somebody has any idea where the problem could be?

Main

```
if name == "main":
    for _ in range(N):
        quotes = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(QUERY.format(random.random())).read())
        prices = {}
        for quote in quotes:
            stock, bid_price, ask_price, price = getDataPoint(quote)
            prices[stock] = price
            print ("Quoted %s at (bid:%s, ask:%s, price:%s)" % (stock, bid_price, ask_price, price))
        print ("Ratio %s" % (getRatio(prices['ABC'],prices['DEF'])))[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Consider adding full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The only keys assigned to your `prices` dictionary are the `stock` values.

In your final print call you try and access the value of (the price of) the key (the stock) `'DEF'`.

Your error: `KeyError: "DEF".` is telling you that there was no stock called `'DEF'`, so Python doesn't no what to do!

So you need to decide how you want to fix this - probably checking before hand that the stock `'DEF'` was returned from your data scrape by seeing `if 'DEF' in prices`.